# Rails Active Record Association Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, models

I have a project in which the following models are set up:

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

has_and_belongs_to_many :user_roles`

`class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users

has_many :user_roles`

`class UserRole< ActiveRecord::Base

has_and_belongs_to_many :users

belongs_to :project`

My problem arises when I want to return every project a user has been involved with and what user role(s) they had on the project *including any projects they have worked on and had no assigned user role for*

I have a feeling `has_many :through` might work but I'm not sure exactly how it would work. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The third class is UserRole perhaps?

Comment: A `Project` has many `User` through `UserProfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :projects, :through => :user_roles


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_roles
  has_many :users, :through => :user_roles


class UserRole< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
```

Comment: So fast to answer! ;) By convention the has_many :through model association works better due to the fact that you have an intermediary model (the through association) that gives you more flexibility for polymorphic associations. A good read for this is [Josh Susser's blog] (http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2006/4/20/many-to-many-dance-off)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Will this still work if a user has been involved with a project but wasn't assigned a user role?

Comment: @Gabe Sure!  You would most likely have a `role` column in your join table `user_roles`, and you could choose to accept `null` values in that column (or designate unassigned roles with some `default value`)

Comment: I was thinking I could go with a "default role" of some sort. It seems hacky, but it would be a relatively simple solution to implement

Comment: @Gabe Yes, I think having `default values` inserted into your table is a pretty good solution - not really hacky!